# How to implement Navigation Drawer for wear os for one activity and settings fregement?

Tags: android, wear-os

I need to extend my application, which basically stands for a MainActivity with a Settings page. I'm trying to implement the `WearableDrawerLayout`, but could not find any good examples, and I know I'm missing something, since the drawer shows up empty.

The activity_main.xml contains the main layout, and the parts for the drawer

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm"
            android:tint="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/screen_percentage_05"
            android:text="asd"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableNavigationDrawerView
        android:id="@+id/top_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout>
```

res/menu/drawer_view.xml (for populating the navigation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="main" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And the MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private WearableNavigationDrawerView mWearableNavigationDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setAmbientEnabled();

        mWearableNavigationDrawer = (WearableNavigationDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.top_navigation_drawer);
        mWearableNavigationDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();

    }
}
```

I still have to connect the activity and the fregement to the menu items, but first I'd like to make the drawer work with two items.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Examples are hard to come by and the documentation is not great. It would be great if they simply gave us the source code for this https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/components/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-usage

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I managed to create a working navigation drawer for wearOS.

Comment: I did get it working. I will update this with a solution.