# How to support multiple screen Wear OS apps with WearableDrawerLayout

Tags: wear-os

I have been looking for examples on WearableDrawerLayout but there don't seem to be many. I specifically want to support multiple screens, a main screen and a configuration screen for now. Examples have been challenging to find. The [Wear navigation and actions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions) figure 1 is a great visual, but the supporting code only gets me so far. One of the things not covered is if multiple activities are used or if toggling setVisibility on layouts is a better option. I am assuming the latter but wanted to see what was the norm.

I also looked at the [planets example](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/master/WearDrawers/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/weardrawers/MainActivity.java) but it just changes the image in a single screen. The [code lab for navigations and actions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/wear-nav-action/index.html#0) on the page was deprecated as well. I would have thought this would be a common pattern and there would be more examples. I guess that was concerning as well. I have seen others on SO mention a [lack of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209511/how-to-implement-navigation-drawer-for-wear-os-for-one-activity-and-settings-fre).

[This documentation](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/components/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-usage) gives a great visual of how it should work, but there is no code to reference how the different screens are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last used the `WearableDrawerLayout` so my approach may be a bit outdated by now. It was for a similar scenario; a main flow (with multiple screens) and a settings screen. This is what I did:

**The layout file**

- A root element of type `WearableDrawerLayout`
- Two `FrameLayout` child views (one for the main flow and one for the settings screen)
- One (deprecated) `WearableNavigationDrawer` child view (replace with a `WearableNavigationDrawerView`)

**The Activity**

- Use the layout file above (obviously...)
- Add the settings fragment to its dedicated `FrameLayout` container
- Handle navigation between different fragments in the main flow using the other `FrameLayout` container (You can probably skip this if your main screen is static)
- Handle selection events in an internal class that extends `WearableNavigationDrawerAdapter` by simply toggling the visibility of the two Fragment containers

I'm not sure if this is the best way. I'm not sure there *is* a best way. It most likely depends on the complexity of your screens etc. You might be able to do it by toggling the visibility directly on layouts/views as you suggest.

I *do* know that the implementation above has been out in production for many years now without any issues.